# Bootstrap 3 - Removing too much space between input fields with a dash in between

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have input boxes as:

[image]

but getting:

[image]

Is there any way i can remove the extra whitespace in between and get desired output without using css margins. My codes is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 employerEin">
        <input type="text" name="employerEIN1" maxlength="2" size="2" value=""
               class="form-control" id="employerEIN1" title="EIN">
    </div>
    <span class="col-md-1 employerEin">-</span>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="employerEIN2" maxlength="7" size="7" value=""
               class="form-control" id="employerEIN2" title="EIN">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `.form-inline` class to your `<form>`

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="employerEIN1" maxlength="2" size="2" value="" class="form-control" id="employerEIN1" title="EIN">
            -
            <input type="text" name="employerEIN2" maxlength="7" size="7" value="" class="form-control" id="employerEIN2" title="EIN">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT: Added additional code due to OP's comment**

Just add the `.form-inline` class to the enclosing div to make those two fields behave inline, then continue adding other fields as necessary

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- add the .form-inline class to the enclosing div -->
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <input type="text" name="employerEIN1" maxlength="2" size="2" value="" class="form-control" id="employerEIN1" title="EIN">
        -
        <input type="text" name="employerEIN2" maxlength="7" size="7" value="" class="form-control" id="employerEIN2" title="EIN">
    </div>

    <!-- add other form elements as needed -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="field3" maxlength="2" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="field4" maxlength="7" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: my form has other inputs also and i don't want them to be inline. Are you referring to nested forms? Not sure that was possible